# How to use plugin in only one component using Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am making a simple blog website with nuxt.js, I need to import editor only in one component, I don't want to use `nuxt.config.js`. This is what I am trying to do, but it's seems not working.

```js
//Inside '~/plugins/vue2-editor'
import Vue from "vue";
import Vue2Editor from "vue2-editor";
Vue.use(Vue2Editor);
export default {Vue2Editor}
```

```html
//Inside component
<template>
  <div class="text-editor">
    <client-only>
       <Vue2Editor/>
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {Vue2Editor} from '~/plugins/vue2-editor'
export default {
components: {
    Vue2Editor
  },
}
</script>
```

[image]

What should i do?

Comment: This will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805180/how-to-solve-document-not-defined-error-when-using-nuxtjs-vue2-editor

Comment: @tho-masn rather not recommend using `require` for Vue.

Comment: Otherwise, this issue is majorly asked on SO and a quick search can help you here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn‘t see it was using require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use it in only one component, import it (vue2-editor) just there (no need for a plugin). Then, your usage of `client-only` should be good.
More details could be found in this other answer: [How to fix navigator / window / document is undefined in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585)

Otherwise, you could use a dynamic import but I'm not sure this is needed in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825061/8816585

Answer (score 0):

The way I got it:

**1. In your nuxt.config.js:**

```
plugins: [ { src: "~/plugins/vue2-editor", ssr: false } ],
```

**2. Create a file with the name vue2-editor.js in the plugin folder of your nuxt project, that has the following:**

```
import Vue from "vue";

import Vue2Editor from "vue2-editor";

Vue.use(Vue2Editor);
```

**3. Where you want to use the editor (no Import is necessary):**

```
<client-only placeholder="Loading Your Editor...">
    <vue-editor placeholder="Write Something..." >
    </vue-editor>
</client-only>
```

Comment: This imports it globally, not in one component.