# Register Quill in Nuxt with image resize module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, quill

Here in my Nuxt project I am using [vue2-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-editor) and [Quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill) along with [quill-image-resize-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-image-resize-module).
I am able to use the vue-editor but don't know to use the Quill. When I import the Quill it says document is not defined.
Here is my code.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <client-only> <vue-editor class="editor" v-model="arr['desc']"  /></client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
let VueEditor
if (process.client) {
  VueEditor = require('vue2-editor').VueEditor
}
import Quill from "quill"
window.Quill = Quill
const ImageResize = require("quill-image-resize-module").default
Quill.register("modules/imageResize", ImageResize)
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      arr: {},
    }
  },
  components: { VueEditor },
 
}
</script>
```

My dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
  "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
  "nuxt-buefy": "^0.4.13",
  "quill": "^1.3.7",
  "quill-image-resize-module": "^3.0.0",
  "vue2-editor": "^2.10.3",
  "vuexfire": "^3.2.5"
},
```

Comment: Hi, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69307486/8816585) and tell us if you still have some issues.

Comment: The error is gone and the console shows the warning of quill overwriting modules. But the resize module is not working.

Comment: What does it mean `not working`? Also, this is a free feature or maybe a paid one? (not sure when I saw that but I know that sometimes those are paid features)

Comment: Its not a paid feature. After adding that module we should be able to resize the image by just double-clicking on image.

Comment: I am just dropping it for now. Will see in the future and if I find a solution I will post here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vue-quill-editor, it is compatible with nuxt and no need to integrate between vue2-editor and Quill anymore.
You can check the installation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-quill-editor
Then add a file config in plugins like this (for example):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueQuillEditor from 'vue-quill-editor'

Vue.use(VueQuillEditor)
```

And add it into plugins in **nuxt.config.js**.

Comment: I changed my approach and found the solution at that time only.