# Vue2Editor not working in Nuxt app when accessing page directly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Vue2Editor in my Nuxt app on a single page. Whenever I test the app and navigate to the page from another page on the app, it loads fine without any issues. But when I test and try to open that page directly, the app fails with the following error. I've tried to dynamically import the vue-editor package but that hasn't worked so far. Any ideas how I can make this import work on the page when trying to directly access it?

[image]

***nuxt.config.js***

```
plugins: [{src: './plugins/vue2-editor', ssr: true}]
```

***plugins/vue2-editor.js***

```
import Vue from 'vue'

if (process.BROWSER_BUILD) {
    const VueEditor = require('vue2-editor')
    Vue.use(VueEditor)
}
```

***my_page.vue***

```
<template><div><vue-editor></vue-editor></div></template>
<script>
...
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor';
components: {
     VueEditor
}
...
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use plugin in only one component using Nuxt.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298099/how-to-use-plugin-in-only-one-component-using-nuxt-js)

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can import locally, on the client with the following

```js
export default {
  components: {
    [process.browser && 'VueEditor']: () => import('vue2-editor'),
  }
}
```

Rather than having it defined globally (especially if you use it only in a few pages).

Otherwise, wrapping it in between `<client-only>` tags could be a good idea too.
More detailed answer [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69307486/8816585).

Comment: Oddly I'm not getting any change in behavior when adding `<client-only>`

Comment: @mojojojo8 my answer is a bit more complete than that here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it wrapping the component to be client side only?
Problem comes that when you access directly to the page you are Server Side Rendering and `document` doesn't exists on server.

`<client-only><vue-editor/></client-only>`

If not working try setting the plugin as `ssr: false`

`plugins: [{src: './plugins/vue2-editor', ssr: false}]`

Comment: It's `mode: 'client'` nowadays, `ssr: false` is deprecated.